# Unable to start debugger on Older version of Visual Studio (2003) Under Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, .net

For this project I needed to install and run VS 2003 on Windows 7 using IIS 6.0 with Framework 1.1 on my sever because there was old VS2003 C# code on a remote server that needed updating and did not have VS 2003 installed only the DLL, PDB, aspx, and aspx.cs files. After porting the code over and making the needed changes on my local server, I discovered that while I could browse the page, I could not run the page with debugger and got this error: "... Unable to start debugging on the web server. There is no managed code running in the process. In order to attach to a process with the .NET debugger, managed code must be running in the process before attaching." I then started the application without Debugger  and selected the w3wp.exe process for CLR in order to attach the process but I noticed that the process session was set to 0 and I still got that error again.

The following is done in IIS6 :

```
Application created.
DefaultAppPool (.NET framework 1.1 Integrated)(ApplicationPoolIdentity) is used
Browsing the web page works OK. 
Authentication has Integrated Windows and ASP.NET Impersonation enabled.
I have runned aspnet_regiis from all the .net version in order
Set debug="true" in the web.config.
```

Thanks much for your help

Answer (score 5):

Resolution:

1. Right click the ASP.Net project > Properties
2. select Configuration Properties > Debugging
3. Enable the below mentioned entries in 'Debuggers' frame.

   - ASP.Net Debugging
   - Unmanaged code debugging.

Comment: @kleopatra Hi, I am using the same setup as the initial requesterwith one exception:  I am using IIS 7 instead of IIS 6. I performed the steps based on the resolution above which removed the additional error message about 'managed code'. However I now just get the 1st portion of the error message: "Error while trying to run project.: Unable to start debugging on the web server".

Comment: VS 2003 would not allow me to enable both. After enabling ASP.NET Debugging, a different error appeared. But it's gotten me a step further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it.

1. Delete the virtual directory in IIS
2. Create the new virtual directory with different name other than the old one and configure the new virtual directory name in your visual studio solution.