# .Net 1.1 can't run debugging in Visual Studio 2003

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2003

I'm trying to start WebProject in VS2003, but I got the error:"Unable to start debugging on the web server. The project is not configured to be debugged."
I use Visual Studio 2003 on WinXP on virtual drive with IIS 5.1
I already tried to change properties on catalog, where project placed. It didn't make any change. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: _"Visual Studio 2003 on WinXP on virtual drive with IIS 5.1"_ - poor you. Anyway did you read [Unable to start debugger on Older version of Visual Studio (2003) Under Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633065/unable-to-start-debugger-on-older-version-of-visual-studio-2003-under-windows)?

Comment: Yes, and I did advices from there too. Still not working=(

Comment: Do you have this line <compilation debug="true"> in web.config?